# svn update and existing files - need files from repository

Tags: svn, svn-update

when I commit to svn repositary file FILE.TXT and in other computer I want update from this repository, but in directory FILE.TXT exist..its write some *svn: Failed to add file 'FILE.TXT': object of the same name already exists* 
It can do with `svn update --force` ..but FILE.TXT is same, which was there earlier in directory ..
I need have after `svn update` file from repository. I can do it when i delete original file and make `svn update` but i want do this automatic..
Best way some parameter of `svn`

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have in repository files with same name but with different case **FILE.TXT** and **file.txt** and in this case on Windows this situation occurs. Check [this](http://support.beanstalkapp.com/customer/portal/articles/68097-issue-with-%22name-already-exists%22-or-%22cannot-find-the-file-specified%22-in-windows).

Comment: I write FILE.TXT as example..i know case problem and it is in Linux.. My Problem in short: I want update file from repozitory, but file with samename in my directory exists.. and i want do this automatic with one svn command (no delete file and update)

Comment: I don't think you can do with "one svn command". You can update to newly created directory (there will be no conflict) then using text diff or GUI add to new one what is missed from the old one, then commit. After that - you should not see this problem again.